Ubuntu server 24.04 multiple reboot
I have a k3s cluster with 3 nodes (ubuntu2, ubuntu3 and ubuntu4). Each nodes are an Ubuntu 24.04 server OS.
On each of them I have enabled the UnattendedUpgrades in the nights.
The problem is that on ubuntu2 I have multiple reboot per day! (of different number but from 3-4 to even 7-8) at different time of day&night. On the other 2 nodes I have less than 1 per day (that seems the correct number).
On ubuntu2 for now I found different timer in the journalctl that cause the restart and I just disable them
sudo systemctl disable apt-daily.timer
sudo systemctl disable apt-daily-upgrade.timer
sudo systemctl stop apt-daily.timer
sudo systemctl stop apt-daily-upgrade.timer
sudo systemctl stop ua-timer.service
sudo systemctl disable ua-timer.service
sudo systemctl stop ua-timer.timer
sudo systemctl disable ua-timer.timer

but 1) I don't know if there is still something missing 2) this don't seems the really root cause of the problem, because on the other two machine are enabled and don't get rebootted.
Just to give you an idea of the problem this are the reboot of yesterday and today. Only 3 with the (X) out of 11 are made by me. All the other was triggered from somethingelse.
guido@ubuntu2:~$ last reboot
reboot   system boot  6.8.0-49-generic Tue Nov 19 10:40   still running  (X)
reboot   system boot  6.8.0-48-generic Tue Nov 19 09:42 - 10:38  (00:55) (X)
reboot   system boot  6.8.0-48-generic Tue Nov 19 05:15 - 10:38  (05:22)
reboot   system boot  6.8.0-48-generic Mon Nov 18 21:28 - 10:38  (13:09) (X)
reboot   system boot  6.8.0-48-generic Mon Nov 18 19:44 - 21:26  (01:41)
reboot   system boot  6.8.0-48-generic Mon Nov 18 18:27 - 21:26  (02:59)
reboot   system boot  6.8.0-48-generic Mon Nov 18 15:38 - 21:26  (05:48)
reboot   system boot  6.8.0-48-generic Mon Nov 18 15:30 - 21:26  (05:55)
reboot   system boot  6.8.0-48-generic Mon Nov 18 14:37 - 21:26  (06:49)
reboot   system boot  6.8.0-48-generic Mon Nov 18 05:32 - 21:26  (15:54)
reboot   system boot  6.8.0-48-generic Mon Nov 18 03:14 - 21:26  (18:11)

And to give an overall idea, on ubuntu3 I have less than 1 restart per day.
Also today I just run the last updated and got the last version of the kernel (6.8.0-49). I don't know if that could help.
Searching for error in journalctl I have this "occurrent" error at each reboot
guido@ubuntu2:~$  journalctl --since "1 days ago" -p 3
Nov 18 14:37:23 ubuntu2 kernel: x86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS.
Nov 18 14:37:23 ubuntu2 kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT, Field [CAP1] at bit offset/length 64/32 exceeds size of target Buffer (64 bits) (20230628/dsopcode-198)
Nov 18 14:37:23 ubuntu2 kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB._OSC due to previous error (AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT) (20230628/psparse-529)
-- Boot 5b5571a916b64a3ebc9731a6b6e7444f --
Nov 18 15:30:44 ubuntu2 kernel: x86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS.
Nov 18 15:30:44 ubuntu2 kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT, Field [CAP1] at bit offset/length 64/32 exceeds size of target Buffer (64 bits) (20230628/dsopcode-198)
Nov 18 15:30:44 ubuntu2 kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB._OSC due to previous error (AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT) (20230628/psparse-529)
-- Boot 72b8586898c14d759b4f10756c4db9d2 --
Nov 18 15:38:07 ubuntu2 kernel: x86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS.
Nov 18 15:38:07 ubuntu2 kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT, Field [CAP1] at bit offset/length 64/32 exceeds size of target Buffer (64 bits) (20230628/dsopcode-198)
Nov 18 15:38:07 ubuntu2 kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB._OSC due to previous error (AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT) (20230628/psparse-529)
Nov 18 16:51:36 ubuntu2 sudo[117623]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): conversation failed
Nov 18 16:51:36 ubuntu2 sudo[117623]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): auth could not identify password for [guido]
-- Boot 446fb39d4d6c42fca40e0162a7ae58cb --
Nov 18 18:27:04 ubuntu2 kernel: x86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS.
Nov 18 18:27:04 ubuntu2 kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT, Field [CAP1] at bit offset/length 64/32 exceeds size of target Buffer (64 bits) (20230628/dsopcode-198)
Nov 18 18:27:04 ubuntu2 kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB._OSC due to previous error (AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT) (20230628/psparse-529)
-- Boot bb524db3dbd94271b7f71a8ef5b33723 --
Nov 18 19:44:51 ubuntu2 kernel: x86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS.
Nov 18 19:44:51 ubuntu2 kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT, Field [CAP1] at bit offset/length 64/32 exceeds size of target Buffer (64 bits) (20230628/dsopcode-198)
Nov 18 19:44:51 ubuntu2 kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB._OSC due to previous error (AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT) (20230628/psparse-529)
Nov 18 21:25:40 ubuntu2 sudo[156493]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): conversation failed
Nov 18 21:25:40 ubuntu2 sudo[156493]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): auth could not identify password for [guido]
Nov 18 21:26:35 ubuntu2 iscsid[1005]: semop down failed 22
Nov 18 21:26:40 ubuntu2 canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd[798]: daemon shutting down
-- Boot 10acfa7dc8884d59848ddeeadb6cca82 --
Nov 18 21:28:21 ubuntu2 kernel: x86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS.
Nov 18 21:28:21 ubuntu2 kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT, Field [CAP1] at bit offset/length 64/32 exceeds size of target Buffer (64 bits) (20230628/dsopcode-198)
Nov 18 21:28:21 ubuntu2 kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB._OSC due to previous error (AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT) (20230628/psparse-529)
-- Boot 8513572e9b164f9b9469f2b1ad347c63 --
Nov 19 05:15:21 ubuntu2 kernel: x86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS.
Nov 19 05:15:21 ubuntu2 kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT, Field [CAP1] at bit offset/length 64/32 exceeds size of target Buffer (64 bits) (20230628/dsopcode-198)
Nov 19 05:15:21 ubuntu2 kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB._OSC due to previous error (AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT) (20230628/psparse-529)
-- Boot 595e36d7058f4ae383768e44a90cd3c1 --
Nov 19 09:42:40 ubuntu2 kernel: x86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS.
Nov 19 09:42:40 ubuntu2 kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT, Field [CAP1] at bit offset/length 64/32 exceeds size of target Buffer (64 bits) (20230628/dsopcode-198)
Nov 19 09:42:40 ubuntu2 kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB._OSC due to previous error (AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT) (20230628/psparse-529)
Nov 19 10:38:09 ubuntu2 canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd[842]: daemon shutting down
Nov 19 10:38:09 ubuntu2 iscsid[1053]: semop down failed 22
-- Boot adc110945062484495d197fd48bc34a6 --
Nov 19 10:40:05 ubuntu2 kernel: x86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS.
Nov 19 10:40:05 ubuntu2 kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT, Field [CAP1] at bit offset/length 64/32 exceeds size of target Buffer (64 bits) (20230628/dsopcode-198)
Nov 19 10:40:05 ubuntu2 kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB._OSC due to previous error (AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT) (20230628/psparse-529)
guido@ubuntu2:~$

But I dont know how to fix them and if this is related (on ubuntu3 and ubuntu4 I don't have this error).
Any idea to troubleshoot this and find the real root cause?
Thanks!

Check hardware
Hardware issues may be the cause of frequent reboots
